# Login as a User in Ejabberd

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I am using erlang 17.0, ejabberd 14.07. I am trying to create chat application, I have completed registration part. Now I want to login from registered user, but I am not able to login, so How do I login as user on ejabberd.
Basically My question is, How user become an online on ejabberd server(at localhost)?

I know this is very stupid question but I am not able to find any way so guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function yourconnection.login(username,password).

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you have successfully registered user on ejabberd by using command

```
> sudo ejabberdctl registered_users localhost
```

This will list all registered users on localhost node. Hope you will find your user there.

Now as you have successfully set-up your ejabberd(XMPP server). You need XMPP client in order for user to login.

So if you are using java programming language then you should use SMACK XMPP library to connect to ejabberd server. Use this code with your username and password to connect to ejabberd server.

```
// Create a connection to the igniterealtime.org XMPP server.
 XMPPTCPConnection con = new XMPPTCPConnection("igniterealtime.org");
 // Connect to the server
 con.connect();
 // Most servers require you to login before performing other tasks.
 con.login("jsmith", "mypass");
 // Start a new conversation with John Doe and send him a message.
 Chat chat = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(con).createChat("jdoe@igniterealtime.org", new MessageListener() {
     public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
         // Print out any messages we get back to standard out.
         System.out.println("Received message: " + message);
     }
 });
 chat.sendMessage("Howdy!");
 // Disconnect from the server
 con.disconnect();
```

For more detail about this code visit [link](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/XMPPConnection.html).

In case you want to use client other than in Java then here is [list of XMPP client libraries](https://xmpp.org/software/libraries.html)

After connecting to ejabberd server you need to **persist that connection** to send and receive messages further.